# Flutter android text highlighting not working using 'flutter_selectext 0.1.1'

Tags: android, flutter, dart

What client needs we deliver right? the concept of the app is a reading for a religious app, where users can select text and highlight it with color. After searching for the whole day i found a plugin that can do the job i want perfectly.

It is '[flutter_selectext 0.1.1](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_selectext#-readme-tab-)' Just as the gif below.

[image]

Selectable Text exists in current flutter but with default copy,  paste, cut, selectAll which is not adequate for my case.

So Added the package in pubspec.yaml and running the app gives me the below error.

```
Compiler message:
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_selectext-0.1.1/lib/src/selectable_text.dart:90:29: Error: Type 'Gestures.GestureLongPressDragStartDetails' not found.
      BuildContext context, Gestures.GestureLongPressDragStartDetails details) {
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_selectext-0.1.1/lib/src/selectable_text.dart:115:7: Error: Type 'Gestures.GestureLongPressDragUpdateDetails' not found.
      Gestures.GestureLongPressDragUpdateDetails details) {
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_selectext-0.1.1/lib/src/selectable_text.dart:131:32: Error: Type 'Gestures.GestureLongPressDragUpDetails' not found.
  void _handleSingleLongTapEnd(Gestures.GestureLongPressDragUpDetails details) {
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_selectext-0.1.1/lib/src/selectext_editable_text.dart:454:7: Error: The non-abstract class 'SelectableTextEditableTextState' is missing implementations for these members:
 - TextInputClient.connectionClosed
 - TextSelectionDelegate.copyEnabled
 - TextSelectionDelegate.cutEnabled
 - TextSelectionDelegate.pasteEnabled
 - TextSelectionDelegate.selectAllEnabled
Try to either
 - provide an implementation,
 - inherit an implementation from a superclass or mixin,
 - mark the class as abstract, or
 - provide a 'noSuchMethod' implementation.

class SelectableTextEditableTextState extends State<SelectableTextEditableText>
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/text_input.dart:658:8: Context: 'TextInputClient.connectionClosed' is defined here.
  void connectionClosed();
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/text_input.dart:627:12: Context: 'TextSelectionDelegate.copyEnabled' is defined here.
  bool get copyEnabled => true;
           ^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/text_input.dart:624:12: Context: 'TextSelectionDelegate.cutEnabled' is defined here.
  bool get cutEnabled => true;
           ^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/text_input.dart:630:12: Context: 'TextSelectionDelegate.pasteEnabled' is defined here.
  bool get pasteEnabled => true;
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/text_input.dart:633:12: Context: 'TextSelectionDelegate.selectAllEnabled' is defined here.
  bool get selectAllEnabled => true;
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_selectext-0.1.1/lib/src/selectable_text.dart:90:38: Error: 'GestureLongPressDragStartDetails' isn't a type.
      BuildContext context, Gestures.GestureLongPressDragStartDetails details) {
                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_selectext-0.1.1/lib/src/selectable_text.dart:115:16: Error: 'GestureLongPressDragUpdateDetails' isn't a type.
      Gestures.GestureLongPressDragUpdateDetails details) {
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_selectext-0.1.1/lib/src/selectable_text.dart:131:41: Error: 'GestureLongPressDragUpDetails' isn't a type.
  void _handleSingleLongTapEnd(Gestures.GestureLongPressDragUpDetails details) {
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_selectext-0.1.1/lib/src/selectable_text.dart:246:9: Error: No named parameter with the name 'onSingleLongTapDragUpdate'.
        onSingleLongTapDragUpdate: _handleSingleLongTapMoveUpdate,
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/text_selection.dart:1140:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  const TextSelectionGestureDetector({
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_selectext-0.1.1/lib/src/mark_text.dart:81:12: Error: 'SelectableText' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/material/selectable_text.dart' and 'package:flutter_selectext/src/selectable_text.dart'.
    return SelectableText.rich(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_selectext-0.1.1/lib/src/selectext_editable_text.dart:801:22: Error: Method not found: 'FocusScope.ancestorsOf'.
          FocusScope.ancestorsOf(context);
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_selectext-0.1.1/lib/src/selectext_editable_text.dart:1112:28: Error: The method 'reparentIfNeeded' isn't defined for the class 'FocusScopeNode'.
 - 'FocusScopeNode' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/focus_manager.dart' ('/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/focus_manager.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'reparentIfNeeded'.
    FocusScope.of(context).reparentIfNeeded(widget.focusNode);
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception: Errors during snapshot creation: null
build failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 780

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 13s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

My code is just as the Example in the plugin with a little teak on importing as show below.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_selectext/flutter_selectext.dart' as Selector show SelectableText, MarkText;

void main() {
  runApp(new DemoApp());
}

class DemoApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.grey,
      ),
      home: const SelectableTextDemo(),
    );
  }
}

class SelectableTextDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  const SelectableTextDemo({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SelectableTextDemoState createState() => _SelectableTextDemoState();
}

class _SelectableTextDemoState extends State<SelectableTextDemo> {
  List<TextSelection> markList = List();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Selectable Text Demo'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            Selector.MarkText.rich(
              TextSpan(children: [
                TextSpan(
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.amber,
                        fontSize: 30,
                        wordSpacing: 3,
                        shadows: [
                          Shadow(
                              color: Colors.black,
                              offset: Offset(6, 3),
                              blurRadius: 10)
                        ]),
                    text: 'This has mark option'),
                TextSpan(
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.deepPurple,
                    ),
                    text: ' test test test!!'),
              ]),
              handlerMark: (TextSelection selection) {
                setState(() {
                  markList.add(selection);
                });
              },
              markColor: Colors.deepOrange,
              markList: markList,
            ),
            Selector.SelectableText.rich(
              TextSpan(
                children: [
                  TextSpan(
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.amber,
                        fontSize: 30,
                        wordSpacing: 3,
                        shadows: [
                          Shadow(
                              color: Colors.black,
                              offset: Offset(6, 3),
                              blurRadius: 10),
                        ],
                      ),
                      text: 'You have pushed the'),
                  TextSpan(
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.blueAccent,
                      ),
                      text: 'button this many times:'),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

So How do i make this work?

Comment: Hi, abrsh. Could you provide the version of the Flutter SDK you're using (by running `flutter doctor`) and the version of the library you have installed (probably shows on your pubspec.yaml)?

Comment: [√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.9, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.778], locale en-US)


[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)


[√] Android Studio (version 3.5)


[√] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2019.1)


[√] VS Code (version 1.39.2)


[√] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!

And from pubspec.yaml

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"